# Invalid command line argument when install Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Overall summary:
Final result:                  Failed: see details below
Exit code (Decimal):           -2068052377
Start time:                    2023-08-18 11:44:13
End time:                      2023-08-18 11:44:32
Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

Machine Properties:
Machine name:                  MSI
Machine processor count:       12
OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language (10.0.19045)
OS service pack:
OS region:                     Malaysia
OS language:                   English (United States)
OS architecture:               x64
Process architecture:          64 Bit
OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2022
ProductName:                   SQL Server 2022
Type:                          RTM
Version:                       16
SPLevel:                       0
Installation location:         C:\SQL2022\Express_ENU\x64\setup
Installation edition:          Express

Product Update Status:
User selected not to include product updates.

Notice: Please read Microsoft SQL Server Software License Terms at aka.ms/useterms.

User Input Settings:
ACTION:                        Install
ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
ASDATADIR:                     Data
ASLOGDIR:                      Log
ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR
ASSVCACCOUNT:                  
ASSVCPASSWORD:                 
ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            
ASTELSVCACCT:                  
ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              
ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
AZUREARCPROXYSERVER:           
AZUREBILLEDEDITION:
AZUREREGION:                   
AZURERESOURCEGROUP:            
AZURESERVICEPRINCIPAL:         
AZURESERVICEPRINCIPALSECRET:   
AZURESUBSCRIPTIONID:           
AZURETENANTID:                 
BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20230818_114413\ConfigurationFile.ini
ENABLERANU:                    true
ENU:                           true
EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 
EXTSVCPASSWORD:                
FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           
FTSVCACCOUNT:                  
FTSVCPASSWORD:                 
HELP:                          false
IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
IACKNOWLEDGEENTCALLIMITS:      false
INDICATEPROGRESS:              true
INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server
INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             
INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
INSTANCEID:                    SQLEXPRESS
INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS
ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           
ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          
ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         
ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
ISSVCPASSWORD:                 
ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
ISTELSVCACCT:                  
ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              
ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
ISWORKERSVCCERT:               
ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             
ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           
ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
NPENABLED:                     0
PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               
PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              
PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               
PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              
PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
PBPORTRANGE:                   
PID:                           *****
PRODUCTCOVEREDBYSA:            false
QUIET:                         true
QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
SAPWD:                         
SECURITYMODE:                  
SQLBACKUPDIR:                  
SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SQLMAXDOP:                     0
SQLMAXMEMORY:                  2147483647
SQLMINMEMORY:                  0
SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         true
SQLSVCPASSWORD:                
SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           MSI\USER
SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS
SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             
SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  
SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            1
SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               
SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
SQLUSERDBDIR:                  
SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               
SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE:     false
SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
TCPENABLED:                    0
UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
UpdateEnabled:                 false
UpdateSource:                  MU
USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
USESQLRECOMMENDEDMEMORYLIMITS: false

Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20230818_114413\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
Feature:                       Database Engine Services
Status:                        Failed
Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
Component error code:          1639
Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20230818_114413\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=16.0.1000.6&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

Rules with failures or warnings:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20230818_114413\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Since this problem appear when i have uninstall Microsoft SQL Server before, and now fail to install please help me solve this problem

Comment: [Edit] your question and include the output of **fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo c:** The output should be in English.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to manually uninstall remnants from the previous installation using the steps outlined [here](https://sqlcoffee.com/Tips0026.htm). After manually uninstall SQL Server please restart the computer and run SQL Server setup with the [Run as Administrator option](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-run-app-administrator-windows-10).